Flutter The library 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' doesn't export a member with the shown name 'FirebaseOptions'
I just upgraded my Flutter to the latest version (3.22.2), and since then, I kept getting this error in the firebase_options.dart file provided by Firebase when configuring a Firebase project :

The library 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' doesn't export a member with the shown name 'FirebaseOptions'.

at this line in the file :
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' show FirebaseOptions;

I tried reverting to an older Flutter version and reinstalling it, but I still got an issue.
I also tried creating a new Flutter project for a web app with a new Firebase project, and I still got the same error.
Here is the error I get when trying to run the app

Error (Xcode): ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.2.0/lib/firebase_core.dart:8:8: Error: Error when reading '../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_platform_interface-5.1.0/lib/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart': Permission denied
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

Just in case, here is the firebase_options.dart code :
// File generated by FlutterFire CLI.
// ignore_for_file: type=lint
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' show FirebaseOptions;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'
    show defaultTargetPlatform, kIsWeb, TargetPlatform;

/// Default [FirebaseOptions] for use with your Firebase apps.
///
/// Example:
/// ```dart
/// import 'firebase_options.dart';
/// // ...
/// await Firebase.initializeApp(
///   options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
/// );
/// ```
class DefaultFirebaseOptions {
  static FirebaseOptions get currentPlatform {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      throw UnsupportedError(
        'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for web - '
        'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
      );
    }
    switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
      case TargetPlatform.android:
        return android;
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
        return ios;
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for macos - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for windows - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for linux - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      default:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions are not supported for this platform.',
        );
    }
  }
...


Finally, I found the solution to my problem.
After trying to change Flutter versions and Firebase plugin versions, I encountered an error stating that some libraries didn't have permission to access another.
So, I went to the location where all the library files are stored in Flutter and added read, write, and execution rights for all.
This fixed the problem for me, so here are the commands I used:
cd path/to/.pub-cache

For me, it was ~/.pub-cache.
Then I went to hosted/pub.dev:
cd hosted/pub.dev

Finally, I entered this command to grant all rights to everyone for this folder:
sudo chmod -R a+rwx .

I hope this is helpful for you if you encounter the same issue.
